# deploy de angular y nodejs

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, deployment

Hola estoy haciendo mis primeros deploy de Angular y Nodejs. Ya tengo mi servidor creado e hice el `ng build --configuration production` en Angular, me crea mi carpeta `/dist` la cual llevo a Nodejs y aplico `app.use(express.static('dist'));`.
En local funciona , ahora bien mi pregunta es.... si yo despliego en un hosting solo Nodejs la aplicacion web funcionaria con las llamadas a mis endpoints?
Estoy una  tanto liado, si alguien tiene algun dato que me pueda ayudar a entenderlo
Si alguien recomienda algun host para probar esto ya sea gratis o pago agradecido....

O mi servidor Nodejs con las Apis que cree deben estar en un hosting aparte y mi appWeb de angular en otro?